# Path to item in RapidAPI API

Tags: rapidapi, jet-engine

I'm trying to test the JetEngine plugin to get data from API's and display it on a wordpress site. But I'm stuck at the part where the API item path is configured:

[JetEngine Item Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRTsz.jpg)

The test API structure is as follows:

[API data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neheT.jpg)

The result that is displayed on JetEngine is that it was not found. The authentication is correct, as well as the query strings required by the API:

[Query Strings required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5HUe.jpg)

These are the required query strings:

limit=200&offset=0&postal_code='90004'&status='for_sale'

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? I tried with another API that the structure is simple and does not require query strings and it works fine, but not with this other one that I am testing.

I thank you very much in advance for any support.

Best regards.